# Do the symmetrized solutions to the time-independent Schrodinger equation span the symmetric functions?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction, symmetry, schroedinger-equation

Im learning QM from a book and after reading about multiparticle systems (for instance two noninteracting particles), it looks like the author

1. found the solutions to the time-independent Schrodinger equation  (if particles dont interact, use separation of variables)
2. symmetrized/antisymmetrized and normalized all of them
3. discarded redundant symmetric/antisymmetric solutions
4. appended the time dependencies to get the symmetric/antisymmetric stationary states
5. constructed the general solution to the time-dependent Schrodinger equation as a linear combination

So my question is really about the second step: if any solution to the Schrodinger equation is given by $\Psi(\cdot, t) = \sum\limits_{j \in \mathbb{N}} c_j(t) \psi_j(\cdot)$, then why is any symmetric solution to the Schrodinger equation given by $\Psi_s(\cdot, t) = \sum\limits_{j \in \mathbb{N}} c_j(t) \text{Sym}\psi_j(\cdot)$?

I guess equivalently, if $(\psi_j)_{j \in \mathbb{N}}$ is an basis of eigenvectors of $H$ that spans the Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ associated to a multiparticle system, why is $\text{span}(\text{Sym} \psi_j)_{j \in \mathbb{N}}$ dense in the symmetric functions of $\mathcal{H}$?

Note: here
\begin{align*}
\text{Sym} \psi(r_1, \cdots, r_N)
&= \sum\limits_{\sigma \in S_N} \sigma \psi(r_1, \cdots, r_N) \\
&= \sum\limits_{\sigma \in S_N} \psi(r_{\sigma(1)}, \cdots, r_{\sigma(N)})
\end{align*}

Comment: Hint : up to a normalization factor, $\text{Sym}:\mathcal H\to \mathcal H$ is  a continuous projection operator onto the subspace of symmetric wavefunctions.

Comment: @SolubleFish Oh right its linear, thanks!